# Nested rows in Angular Table

Tags: html, angularjs, web, frontend

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "students": {
      "Student1": {
        "number": "15",
        "books": {
          "Mystery": [
            "Book1",
            "Book2"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Student2": {
        "number": "12",
        "books": {
          "Romance": [
            "Book1"
          ],
          "Adventure": [
            "Book1",
            "Book2"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Student3": {
        "number": "116",
        "books": {
        }
      }
    },
    "class": "7th Grade",
    "school": "High School 1"
  }
]
```

I want to display this data as a table on an Angular1 page in the following manner:
[image: Table Desired]

How can I make it so that the columns resize with each other, and how can I have nested ng-repeats as needed?

I tried to have nested tables inside the `student, student-number, and books` columns, and a table within the table in the `books` column, but the alignment was always off, and I couldn't get a default value of `"No Books"` to show up if the `"books"` field was empty.

Here's a [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/fWfy6vZYs2jAK0sgLlcc/) of what I've tried so far.

Comment: can you make a plunker with the code you tried?

Comment: have you tried? put your code here which you have already tried.

Comment: Your array will contain only one object?

Comment: This question was too broad :(

Comment: @Vivz no it can contain multiple objects.

Comment: @Dixit added the plunkr.

Comment: @Y.Hewa added the plunkr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to combine several tables(based on `$scope.base`, `$scope.students`, `$scope.books` arrays, that calculated in controller) into one virtual, desired table via `float:left`(to ensure they located in one row). Docking of rows is provided by setting of their `style:height`, which depends on number of their children. Direct solution will be very complicated due to complicated html markup of table with `rowspan` attributes. Also I added second item(`items.push(items[0])`), to demonstrate, that solution works at case of several items.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var items = [
    {
      "students": {
        "Student1": {
          "number": "15",
          "books": {
            "Mystery": [
              "Book1",
              "Book2"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Student2": {
          "number": "12",
          "books": {
            "Romance": [
              "Book1"
            ],
            "Adventure": [
              "Book1",
              "Book2"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Student3": {
          "number": "116",
          "books": {
          }
        },
        "class": "7th Grade",
        "school": "High School 1"
      }
    }
  ];
  items.push(items[0]);
   
   $scope.base = [];
   $scope.students = [];
   $scope.books = [];
   for(var item of items){
      var temp = $scope.books.length;
      for(var student in item.students){
        if(['class', 'school'].indexOf(student) == -1){
           var studentV = item.students[student];
           $scope.students.push({name:student, number: studentV.number, w: Object.keys(studentV.books).length || 1});
           for(var book in studentV.books)
              $scope.books.push((book + ':' + JSON.stringify(studentV.books[book])).replace(/"/g, ''));       
           if(Object.keys(studentV.books).length == 0)
             $scope.books.push('No books');
        }
      } 
      $scope.base.push({cl: item.students.class, school: item.students.school, w: $scope.books.length - temp});
   }
   
}]);
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.left, table.left th, table.left td {
    border-right: 0px
}
tr {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">           
  <table style='float:left;border-right:0' class='left'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>School</th>
          <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in base' style='height:{{item.w*30}}px'>
          <td>{{item.school}}</td>
          <td>{{item.cl}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

  <table style='float:left' class='left'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Student</th>
          <th>Student-number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in students' style='height:{{item.w*30}}px'>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.number}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Books</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in books track by $index' style='height:30px'>
          <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was wondering if there's a solution without creating separate arrays in the controller?

Comment: @NishantRoy, you have three tables, so you will have three arrays. As I already wrote, it will be very complicated to solve this problem with only one table and initial array, because of need to implement very complicated html structure of resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to create hidden nested tables to show more information upon click.